# Calendar trouble - can't get the correct days

Tags: java, calendar

I have this code inside of a loop:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
        ProdCalendar currentCal = DefaultProdCalendar.get();    
        int workingDaysBefore = 0;
        int workingDaysAfter = 0;       
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();    
        end.setTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());                                  
        start.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);

        // DAYS OF PREV MONTH
        int pDate = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int allDaysThisMonth = end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int allDaysPrevMonth = start.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Where `row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue()` is a date comming form an `xls` file in this format: `15/08/13`

The problem I'm facing is that this line:
`int allDaysPrevMonth = start.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`
is always returning `30`

Why is the `start` Calendar always returning 30? I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm unable to spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to set the time of your `start` like `start.setTime(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());` and after that go 1 month back with `start.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);`.
Otherwise you take the current month (which is decembre) as of today and get the previous month. Novembre has 30 days so `getActualMaximum` returns 30.
What you do is that you`re setting an explicit end date, but not that the corresponding start date. This causes your start date to be after your end date, which surely isn't your desired effect.

Comment: It worked! I knew that I was missing something. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs of [`Calendar#getActualMaximum(field)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29),

> Returns the maximum value that the specified calendar field could have, given the time value of this Calendar. For example, the actual maximum value of the MONTH field is 12 in some years, and 13 in other years in the Hebrew calendar system.

In your case you've given `DAY_OF_MONTH`, which returns the maximum value the `DAY_OF_MONTH` field can have for the given month.

For example,

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(); // Be default, its today, December
System.out.println(start.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // prints 31, as December as 31 days
```

And you change the month, then

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(); // Be default, its today, dec.
start.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10); // Month is set to November
System.out.println(start.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // prints 30, as November as 30 days
```

You always get 30 because, the current month is *December* and when you do `start.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);`, it sets the current month to *November*, and as explained above, since November has 30 days, you get 30 always.

Comment: Yes, but it is wrong. It always returns 30, when the previous month have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days. The result is always teh same - `30`

Comment: @Slim - Check the last 3 lines in the answer.

Comment: But Your code is not setting any date value to Your `Calendar`. You are always using the time of right now. Or have You tested this with some other code also?

Comment: @TarmoR - To whom is that comment intended?

Comment: It was meant to the original poster, Slim. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();

here,you get the start is current month -- December.
then,you do noting with it but go back just one month,here :start.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
finally,you getActualMaximum of "start"...of cauz, there is 30 the maxday in november。。。